# Find Center of $\mathbf{UT(3, \mathbb{R})}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory

For reference, if $R$ denotes either $\mathbb{Z}$, $\mathbb{Q}$, $\mathbb{R}$, or $\mathbb{C}$, a matrix $A = (a_{ij}) \in M_{n}(R)$ is called **unitriangular** if all diagonal entries $a_{ii}$ are $1$ and all entries $a_{ij}$ $(i>j)$ below the diagonal are $0$ (i.e., an upper triangular matrix with all entries along the main diagonal being $1$):

$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & a_{12} &  a_{13} & a_{14} & \cdots & a_{1\, n-1} & a_{1n} \\ 0 & 1 & a_{23} & a_{24} & \cdots & a_{2\,n-1}& a_{2n} \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & a_{34} & \cdots & a_{3\,n-1} & a_{3n} \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & \cdots & a_{4\,n-1}& a_{4n} \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots & \vdots \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1 & a_{n-1\,n}\\0 & 0& 0& 0 & \cdots & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$

The set of all unitriangular $(n\times n)-$matrices with entries in $\mathbb{R}$ is a group under matrix multiplication, called the unitriangular group $UT(n,\mathbb{R})$.

**I need to describe the center of $\mathbf{UT(3, \mathbb{R})}$.**

To that effect, I took two matrices in $UT(3, \mathbb{R})$, $A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & a_{12} & a_{13} \\ 0 & 1 & a_{23} \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$ and $B =\begin{pmatrix} 1 & b_{12} & b_{13} \\ 0 & 1 & b_{23} \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix} $ and multiplied:

$AB = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & a_{12} & a_{13} \\ 0 & 1 & a_{23} \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & b_{12} & b_{13} \\ 0 & 1 & b_{23} \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & b_{12}+a_{12} & b_{13}+a_{12}b_{23}+a_{13} \\ 0 & 1 & b_{23}+a_{23} \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$

and

$BA = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & b_{12} & b_{13} \\ 0 & 1 & b_{23} \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & a_{12} & a_{13} \\ 0 & 1 & a_{23} \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & a_{12}+b_{12} & a_{13}+b_{12}a_{23}+b_{13} \\ 0 & 1 & a_{23}+b_{23} \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & b_{12}+a_{12} & a_{13}+b_{12}a_{23}+b_{13} \\ 0 & 1 & b_{23}+a_{23} \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$.

From this, I discovered that, in order to have $AB = BA$, I would need $b_{13}+a_{12}b_{23}+a_{13} = a_{13}+b_{12}a_{23} + b_{13}$, or, $a_{12}b_{23}=b_{12}a_{23}$.

Therefore, I concluded that the center of $UT(3,\mathbb{R})$ must be all matrices of the form $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & x & c_{13} \\ 0 & 1 & y \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$ for fixed $x$ and $y$ because, then if $A,B \in $ this set, then

$AB = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & x & a_{13} \\ 0 & 1 & y \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & x & b_{13} \\ 0 & 1 & y \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2x & b_{13}+xy+a_{13} \\ 0 & 1 & 2y \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2x & a_{13}+xy+b_{13} \\ 0 & 1 & 2y \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & x & b_{13} \\ 0 & 1 & y \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & x & a_{13} \\ 0 & 1 & y \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}  = BA$

**Is this correct? Is there more to it than that? Does this set that I exhibited exhaust all possibilities for $\mathbf{C(UT(3,\mathbb{R}))}$** (center of the group, sometimes denoted $Z(UT(3,\mathbb{R}))$, although I like to reserve $Z$ for the centralizer)**?**

**If not, please let me know what would be correct and how to show it.**

Thanks.

Comment: I have tried to add an answer as minute as possible;Do have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$AB=BA$ is the same as $a_{12}b_{23}=b_{12}a_{23}$ by your calculation. This is to hold for *all* choices of $b_{12},b_{23},$ for $A$ to be in the center. Taking for example $b_{23}=1,b_{12}=0$ we have $a_{12}=0.$ Similarly $a_{23}=0.$ I think that's all that holds for $A$ in the center, the third entry arbitrary.

**Added explanation:**

To see the conclusion better, suppose we put $p=a_{1,2},q=a_{23}$ as two of the three elements of $A,$ and for the arbitrary matrix $b$ let $x=b_{12},y=b_{23}.$ Then the equation for $AB=BA$ becomes that $py=qx,$ since one can see the upper right entries of $AB,BA$ are automatically equal in any case.

The key thing to keep in mind is that, if $A$ is to lie in the center, it must commute with *all* possible $B.$ This means that the equation $py=qx$ is to hold for *any* choices of $x,y.$ Choice 1: $y=1,x=0$ gives $p \cdot 1 =q \cdot 0,$ i.e. $p=0.$ Choice 2: $y=0,x=1$ gives $p \cdot 0=q \cdot 1,$ i.e. $q=0.$ So $p=q=0$ follows if $A$ is in the center. As you already noted, the value of the upper right entry of $A$ is arbitrary, so the typical element of the center has $0$'s below diagonal, $1$'s on the diagonal, two $0$'s in the diagonal above that, and an arbitrary element in the upper right position.

One should check separately that any matrix as above described indeed lies in the center. That follows from the analysis, but a concrete computation is simply done.

Comment: I'm a little confused by your explanation. How does it relate to what I wrote, and is my answer correct? If not, how do I rephrase my answer to better reflect what you're saying?

Comment: In your answer you have arbitrary "fixed" $x,y$ where there *must* be $0$'s via what I show. The presence of $c_{13}$ could just as well be written as a $t$ (to denote an arbitrary real).

Comment: oh they have to be $0$s? I'm not entirely sure I see why. Can you write out some matrices? If that's too much work, I understand, and I'll try to figure it out later, but I'm a very visual person and sometimes I need to see things in order to really conceptualize them properly.

Comment: @JessyCat I just added some explanation which may clear it up.

Comment: but why are the only two possible choices for $y$ $1$ and $0$?

Comment: JessyCat-- By definition the center is the set of those matrices each of which commutes with *every* matrix in the group. If you set up $E$ as a specific matrix with rows [1,1,0],[0,1,0][0,0,1] and $F$ as the specific matrix with rows [1,0,0],[0,1,1],[0,0,1] then given $A$ in the center $A$ must commute with *each* of $E,F$ individually. Work out the equations and it will show that the (1,2) and (2,3) entries of $A$ must be $0$ in order that $A$ be in the center.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48489/discussion-between-coffeemath-and-jessy-cat).

Comment: yeah I still don't know how to show that $a_{12}b_{23} = b_{12}a_{23} \implies a_{12} = 0, a_{23} = 0$.

Comment: I think I understand now what you were trying to say. I'll take a look at this on the train on my way to class.

Comment: Jessy-Check "chat" with more (hope it all clears up).

Comment: @coffemath yeah it's all ok now. Thank you. Sorry for getting grouchy.

Answer (score 1):

Consider  $A=$\begin{bmatrix} 1 &a_{12} &a_{13}\\0 & 1 & a_{23}\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}

,  $B_1$\begin{bmatrix} 1 &1 &0\\0 & 1 & 1\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}

$B_2$\begin{bmatrix} 1 &0 &1\\0 & 1 & 1\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}

and $B_3$\begin{bmatrix} 1 &0 &a_{13}\\0 & 1 & 0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}

And perform $AB_1=B_1A;AB_2=B_2A$.

You will get equations like $a_{13}+a_{23}=a_{12}+a_{23}\implies a_{12}=a_{23} $ from the first one.

From the second one we get $a_{12}=0$.

Check from the third  one that $AB_3=B_3A\forall A\in UT(3,\Bbb R)$

So the center of $UT(3,\Bbb R)$ contains matrices of type $B_3$.

Comment: I did not really get what you meant ;in order to find the center of a group you need to take particular examples and then arrive at a conclusion

Comment: These are not just "examples", these are generators of the group so each commutator relation of them can be extended to any element of the group.

Comment: @BogaertsMarc yes, I get that now. At the time I didn't.